# how can i remove currency sign from postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a database where i want to get the max or min value but because of the $ sign its giving me some error. I tried to delete one by one from the codebase it'll take time so how can i delete the sign or how can  i find the max or min from that database in postgresql

Comment: Don't store numbers as strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct, long-term solution is to not store numbers as strings.

As a workaround until you fix your datamodel, you can use the `replace()` function to remove the `$` sign, then convert the string to a number:

```
replace(the_column, '$', '')::numeric
```

You can apply min() and max() on that value.

If you have a "formatted" number, you might want to remove the grouping symbol as well and maybe you need to replace the decimal separator with a `.` to be able to convert this string to a proper number.

Again: the correct solution is to convert that column to `numeric`

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the data model by altering the table:

```
alter table t alter column col type number using ( replace(col, '$', '')::numeric );
```

Then arithmetic operations on the column will work.